# Was the Grim Reaper originally depicted with a scythe or a sickle?

Tags: underworld, history, iconography, angels, weapons

Was the Grim Reaper originally depicted with a scythe or a sickle? I have seen both versions of the Angel of Death's weapon and was wondering which one is considered the older, more original version.

Related question: [What is the origin of Grim Reaper?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/7679/what-is-the-origin-of-grim-reaper)

Comment: You might have to specify what you mean by "grim reaper". As far as I'm aware, there are multiple figures that can be called that to various extents from different mythologies. Many of them served as an inspiration to what we *nowadays* call "Grim Reaper". That figure itself has changed over time as well.

Comment: @VLAZ Whichever one is the earliest.

Answer (score 1):

in greek mythology, the king of the titans, Chronos, carried a sickle. cronus, the harvesting god, carried a scythe. The grim reaper was a combination of the two and carried a sickle.